# docker inspect splunkImage Container ID: Warining: cannot create \"/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk

Tags: docker-compose, x86-64, splunk, arm64, rancher

My test.sh file contains
start () {
visible=$(grep is_visible $base_path/default/app.conf | awk -F= '{gsub(/ /, "", $2);print $2}')
run_docker=(
docker run -d
--name $name
-v $base_path:/opt/splunk/etc/apps/$name
-v $base_path/test:/opt/splunk/etc/apps/test
-p ${PORT:=8001}:8000
--platform linux/amd64
-e "SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license"
-e 'SPLUNK_PASSWORD=changeme'
-e 'SPLUNK_HOME_OWNERSHIP_ENFORCEMENT=false'
-e 'SPLUNK_USER=root'
splunk/splunk:latest
)

Execution:
./test.sh start

http://localhost:8001/en-US/app/search
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

While insptecting the docker container image getting this following warining. Please help to resolve.

Splunk image exited 1 with warning

"ExitCode": 1,
"Output": "\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/introspection"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/watchdog"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/client_events"\nERROR - Failed opening "/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk/btool.log": Permission denied\n"

My machine is Mac M1 Apple silicon
Enabled Rossetta2
Changed arch from ARM to Intel

Have installed rancher desktop

pulling the latest splunk

The image is exited 1 with warning
Warning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/introspection"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/watchdog"\n\nWarning: cannot create "/opt/splunk/var/log/client_events"\nERROR - Failed opening "/opt/splunk/var/log/splunk/btool.log": Permission denied